# How these strange override rules with erasure can be explained?

Tags: java, generics, overriding, type-erasure

What is happening here and how to understand it?

```
class C<T> {
    public T id(T x) {
        return null;
    }
}

class D extends C<String> {
    public Integer id(Integer x) {  // compiles! but T shall be String ???
        return 7;
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(new D().id("7")); // null
        System.out.println(new D().id(7));   // 7

    }
```

By the way if I declare D like this, compilation fails with `Name clash: The method id(Object) of type D has the same erasure as id(T) of type C<T> but does not override it:`

```
class D extends C<String> {
    public Object id(Object x) {   // compile error !
        return 7;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @Override annotation to check if the method really overrides another method.

In the first case you will have 2 methods, one that expect String and another that expect Integer.

In the second case you created the same method that already exits after type erasure of supertype.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler replaces your type parameters with `Object` after it's checked that they've been used correctly.  So after compilation, your original class `D` has

```
public Object id(Object x)
```

and

```
public Integer id(Integer x)
```

which is perfectly fine.

However, in your second example, there are two versions of `public Object id(Object x)` in the same class.

Comment: Nitpick: C’s id method isn’t public in OP’s example. (still +1)